# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2' by using Pyodide

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, psycopg2, pyodide

I have only added this code to the *ts file of this repository(https://github.com/ibdafna/webdash) which works fine in my conda environment.

```
from sqlalchemy.engine.create import create_engine
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

url = 'postgresql://mmnikx ....'
engine =create_engine(url)
now = datetime.now()
df=pd.DataFrame([now])

df.to_sql(
    "TestDBTime",  # table name
    con=engine,
    if_exists='append',
    index=False
)
```

I am trying to connect to a database using sqlalchemy. This piece of code is inside a typescript file. Running dash with pyodide inside a html file. I think the problem is that I can't load psycopg2 because it is not a pure python package and the pyodide version of sqlalchemy does not have this package.

How could I avoid this problem? My main problem is getting information. Connecting to a database seems to be the best option. I tried to install pygsheets, but no success.

```
Uncaught (in promise) PythonError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 415, in eval_code
    CodeRunner(
  File "/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 296, in run
    coroutine = eval(self.code, globals, locals)
  File "<exec>", line 19, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 2, in create_engine
  File "/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 309, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 560, in create_engine
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 782, in dbapi
    import psycopg2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
    at new_error (pyodide.asm.js:14:246344)
    at pyodide.asm.wasm:0xe6e27
    at pyodide.asm.wasm:0xe6f25
    at Object.Module._pythonexc2js (pyodide.asm.js:14:943337)
    at Object.Module.callPyObjectKwargs (pyproxy.gen.ts:409:12)
    at Object.Module.callPyObject (pyproxy.gen.ts:415:17)
    at PyProxyClass.apply (pyproxy.gen.ts:1191:19)
    at Object.apply (pyproxy.gen.ts:1064:18)
    at Object.runPython (api.ts:57:25)
    at r (worker.js:62:35)
```

Answer (score 2):

Pyodide, or anything running in a web browser, does not support TCP/IP connections. You need a TCP/IP connection to connect to the remote PostgreSQL database. psycopg2, or any other normal SQL database driver cannot work with Pyodide.

Web browsers cannot do TCP/IP connections as it would be a security nightmare as they could connect to any application in your local network.

Comment: I think your first sentence should say "does not support" :)

Comment: Ah, didn't realise this when I wrote my answer! In that case, I guess to solve their problem OP had better create an API to serve the data needed for the application via HTTP requests?

Comment: I assume in long term there will be SQL-over-HTTPS-proxy services. I am not sure if there is yes as making a connection from the web browser is a niche use case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. The idea I have is to save information obtained in some way. I've been trying to establish a connection with postgres or using pgsheets. Any other ideas would be great.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/PostgREST/postgrest or Firebase that offers native HTTP API.

Answer (score 0):

SQLAlchemy requires a driver library to make connections to a particular database.

It is possible to specify which library to use in in connection string, so you don't necessarily need to use `psycopg2`, the default driver for PostgreSQL.

You could have `postgresql+asyncpg://user:pass@host:port/db` to use `asyncpg`, for example.

This may not be a good alternative (unless you *want* async code). [A full list of database driver libraries for PostgreSQL supported by SQLAlchemy is available here.](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html) Perhaps one of them will work?

Alternatively, you could try installing the `psycopg2-binary` package instead, which I've had frequent recourse to, given how fiddly later versions of `psycopg2` can be! Note that it is not officially recommended for production, however.

Finally, it sounds like you don't really care if the data are stored in a postgres DB? If the data are lightweight enough that you looked into a spreadsheet as an option, why not consider a SQLite database? Then the database is simply a file that your application has access to. You get `sqlalchemy` support out of the box and switching is as simple as changing the connection string to `sqlite:///path/to/my.db` (where `my.db` is the SQLite database file that you will create).

[I created a stripped down example here, if that option interests you - it's very similar to what I think you are trying to do.](https://github.com/PaddyAlton/simple-sql/blob/main/create_database.py)

Comment: I keep getting the following error. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'  I Try to install it with micropip  and even de binary.  and Yes , i try to save it in google sheets  But no Pyodide support for pgsheets.